# How to create new combobox with c# code?

Tags: c#, events, combobox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ComboBox item = new ComboBox();

        item.Name = "subCat";
        item.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 71);
        item.Width = 200;
        item.Height = 21;
        item.Text = "Choose SubCategori";

        item.Items.Add("test1");

        this.Controls.Add(item);

    }
```

Now I need this created combobox_value_changed event.

Please help me. (Sorry bad english)

Comment: You can access it normally. For example, if you wanted to make that exact method handle `item.SelectedIndexChanged`, all you'd have to do is `item.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;`

Comment: In case this is ASP.NET, control created like this will be lost when page is posted to server.

Answer (score 0):

Let `DynamicCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged` be a method that you want to call on selection index change of the newly created comboBox. then you can assign this to the combobox using the code below:

```
private void DynamicCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Code here
}
// creation statements
item.SelectedIndexChanged += DynamicCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something the following:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = new ComboBox
    {
        Name = "subCat",
        Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 71),
        Width = 200,
        Height = 21,
        Text = "Choose SubCategori"
    };
    item.Items.Add("test1");

    this.Controls.Add(item);

    // assign previously written method
    item.SelectedIndexChanged += DynamicallyCreatedCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    // or
    // assign created in place delegate
    item.SelectedIndexChanged += (objSender, eventArgs) => {/* code here */};
}

// event handler for dynamically created combo box
private void DynamicallyCreatedCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code here
}
```